# Strange lines on the mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

Somehow these strange lines have appeared on my mesh. Also, when I try to assign a material to a part of the mesh, everything gets distorted. How do I fix this?

The distorted mesh:

[image]

I've tried to clear parenting, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: no, the model was made in blender. I'll upload the screenshot of the distorted mesh.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to fix those artifacts. Here's something what might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T3QdLJOBF8

Comment: Hi! Just a quick summary of what was wrong would be helpful to others...